# How to filter GraphQL product query for product type?

Tags: magento-graphql

I have to filter the Magento 2 GraphQL query to filter based on the product type.

```
products(
            filter: {category_id: {eq: "3"}},
            sort: {name: ASC},
            pageSize: 2,
            currentPage: 1
        ) {
            total_count
            items {
                __typename
                name
                sku
                description {
                    html
                }
                short_description {
                    html
                }
                image {
                    url
                    label
                    position
                    disabled
                }
                small_image {
                    url
                    label
                    position
                    disabled
                }
                thumbnail {
                    url
                    label
                    position
                    disabled
                }
                price_range {
                    minimum_price {
                        regular_price {
                            value
                            currency
                        }
                        final_price {
                            value
                            currency
                        }
                        discount {
                            amount_off
                            percent_off
                        }
                    }
                    maximum_price {
                        regular_price {
                            value
                            currency
                        }
                        final_price {
                            value
                            currency
                        }
                        discount {
                            amount_off
                            percent_off
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In this query I am filtering using the category but I want it to filter the product by type.
eg - I only want to fetch the downloadable products.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To filter a GraphQL product query by product type in Magento 2, you can use the filter argument with the ProductFilterInput input type. Here's an example query:

```
query {
  products(filter: {type_id: {eq: "simple"}}) {
    items {
      id
      sku
      name
      price {
        regularPrice {
          value
          currency
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this query, we're using the products query to retrieve a list of products. The filter argument is used to filter the results based on certain criteria, in this case, the type_id field is filtered by the value "simple".

You can replace "simple" with the product type that you want to filter by, such as "configurable", "virtual", "bundle", etc.

Comment: "Field \"type_id\" is not defined by type ProductAttributeFilterInput." I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Yes, did not work for me as well, type_id is not defined. @Deepak did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: not yet @freeLancer_AAS